# Rails Postgres filtering for a jsonb object inside of a jsonb array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

Let's say I have a model `Neighborhood` that has a jsonb[] field `families`, which is an array containing json objects with any type of key value pairing like so `[{"name":"Smiths", "count":4}, {"name":"Miller","out_on_vacation":false}, {"name":"Bennet", "house_color":"red", "count": 4}]`

I want to do an activerecord query to find Neighborhoods for Neighborhoods having certain objects inside their `families` array. 
So if I did something like `Neighborhood.where({families: {count: 4})`, the result would be any Neighborhood models whose families field contain a jsonb object with a key value pairing of `count: 4`. I've played around with a bunch of different queries, but can't seem to get any of them to work without getting an error back. How would I go about writing an Activerecord query to getthe desired results?

**EDIT:**
I had run a migration like so:

```
def change 
  add_column :neighborhoods, :families, :jsonb, array: true, default: [], index: true 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would do something like:

```
Neighborhood.where("families -> 'count' ? 4")
```

This article might help you: http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails

edit: Just noticed that you have an array inside of the jsonb, so this probably won't work.

edit 2: This was answered over on Reddit and worked for me as well. Answering here as a reference for myself.

```
Neighborhood.where %q(families @> '[{"count":?}]'), 4
```

Comment: hmmmm, this still isn't working for me for some reason, I made a migration to add the jsonb[] column which I have posted in the question under the edit header.

whenever I try `Neighborhood.where %q(families @> '[{"count":?}]'), 4` I get a `ERROR: malformed array literal` and a detail saying `"[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.` did you know why this would be by any chance?

Comment: did you use an index by any chance?